# Zpanel 10.1.0 was recently released. Should i bother for client projects?

Tags: security, web-hosting

Zpanel 10.1.0 was released on 27th of July. Has anyone tried it? I know that they had serious security issues with the last version(10.0.2). Should i bother and use this one for client web projects and shared hosting control panel? Have they managed to fix the security issues in the current version?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There will always be lots of security bugs in software like web-based control panels.  You should keep it up to date always, if you must use it at all.

Generally speaking, this is a game of staying one step ahead of attackers, and certainly there are publicly known vulnerabilities in the last version; even if they only effectively fixed one of them you should update your software.

I couldn't find their changelog, but if you can, you should read through it to answer this question.  Bear in mind that vendors *very often* silently fix security bugs without either acknowledging them or annotating the change that fixes them.